# Phonegap native select

Tags: ios, html, cordova

Can I do native select scrolling view with phonegap select box?

```
<select>
  <option value='Agriculture and Fishing'>Agriculture and Fishing</option>
  <option value='Mining and Quarrying'>Mining and Quarrying</option>
  <option value='Manufacturing'>Manufacturing</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Comment: There is not such thing as "native select scrolling view", but yes, if you use the html select, it displays a native UIPickerView

Comment: Why is mine displaying a tooltip?, I am developing for ipad.

Comment: In iPhone will display a scrolling view as you want but not in iPad, it will display a list in tooltip. And I am also could not find the way to change it.

Comment: is there a solution for ipad if I want to show pickerview?

Comment: On iPad it's a UIPickerView too, but they show it on a UIPopover. This is the default behaviour, you can't change it. The only thing you can do is to create a native plugin that shows the native UIPickerView, then use an input type text and launch the native UIPickerView when the onfocus event is triggered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have available a [PickerView plugin](https://github.com/mgcrea/cordova-pickerview/tree/master)

Or you can use [this spinning wheel component](http://cubiq.org/spinning-wheel-on-webkit-for-iphone-ipod-touch) that is like displayed as native